# How to parse stdClass from Amazon API Response to return string

Tags: php, xml, api, amazon-web-services

**Hello I would like to set the Description for magento products using data collected from Amazon api.** I am calling the API and receiving the response however in the logs I get :

> Recoverable Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

The question is how to parse the information into a string so it can be used within magento product details?

```
<?php
require_once '../abstract.php';
require('AmazonApi.php');

class Mage_Shell_Amazon extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{


public function run() {

    //Create API access object
    $public_key = '*********';
    $secret_key = '*********+*******';
    $associate_tag = '*******-21';
    $amazon_api = new AmazonAPI($public_key, $secret_key, $associate_tag);


    //load product by categoryId
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('asin')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description');

    //Array of request parameters
    foreach($products as $prod)
    {
        //load the actual products data
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());

        $asin = $product->getAsin();

        $params_array = array(
            'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
            'IdType' => 'ASIN',
            'ItemId' => $asin ,
            'ResponseGroup' => 'Tracks');

        // returns a list of items for the search query 'Slow Magic'
        $response = $amazon_api->sendRequest($params_array);

        $product->setDescription($restponse);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'description');

        foreach ($response as $restponse)
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($restponse);
        echo '</pre>';

    }

    //        foreach($parsed_xml->OperationRequest->Errors->Error as $error){
    //            echo "Error code: " . $error->Code . "\r\n";
    //            echo $error->Message . "\r\n";
    //            echo "\r\n";
     //        }
       }
     }

        $amazonConnector = new Mage_Shell_Amazon();
        $amazonConnector->run();
```

Sample from Amazon response for one of the products :

```
[Items] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Request] => stdClass Object
            (
                [IsValid] => True
                [ItemLookupRequest] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IdType] => ASIN
                        [ItemId] => B000002OGL
                        [ResponseGroup] => Tracks
                        [VariationPage] => All
                    )

            )

        [Item] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ASIN] => B000002OGL
                [Tracks] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Disc] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Track] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Mustang Sally
                                                [Number] => 1
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Take Me To The River
                                                [Number] => 2
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Chain Of Fools
                                                [Number] => 3
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => The Dark End Of The Street
                                                [Number] => 4
                                            )

                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Destination: Anywhere
                                                [Number] => 5
                                            )

                                        [5] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => I Can't Stand The Rain
                                                [Number] => 6
                                            )

                                        [6] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Try A Little Tenderness
                                                [Number] => 7
                                            )

                                        [7] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Treat Me Right
                                                [Number] => 8
                                            )

                                        [8] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Do Right Woman Do Right Man
                                                [Number] => 9
                                            )

                                        [9] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Mr. Pitiful
                                                [Number] => 10
                                            )

                                        [10] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => I Never Loved A Man
                                                [Number] => 11
                                            )

                                        [11] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => In The Midnight Hour
                                                [Number] => 12
                                            )

                                        [12] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Bye Bye Baby
                                                [Number] => 13
                                            )

                                        [13] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_] => Slip Away
                                                [Number] => 14
                                            )

                                    )

                                [Number] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on specifics with the Amazon API, so the first thing I would do would research on Amazon's documentation on how to get a string description.

If not, looking at that result, the description is structured data. For example, in this case it's a list of tracks and an ID. If you NEED to get a description from that you can first convert the stdClass into an array using:

```
json_decode(json_encode($item), true);
```

And then once that's an array, you could walk through it recursively and compile a string. If it was a one-dimensional array, you could simply use implode with a delimiter to join it together, however in this case it is a multi-dimensional array.

But again, I should re-iterate, this should be the **LAST** resort. Try as hard as you can to find the best practices for displaying descriptions from Amazon first.

Comment: Unfortunately when I add this to my code it doesn't display anything. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: That code doesn't display anything, it only returns something. If you want it to display you have to echo it. 

You can assign it to a variable with `$item = json_decode(json_encode($item), true))`

Comment: My bad , as it doesn't display anything I've meant "NULL" which means that the JSON can't be decoded.