# StdClass Object to String , Iterating through the array

Tags: php, arrays, api, stdclass

Hi I've asked this before but didn't get a correct answer. I am trying to get the Tracks to print from the stdObject. I've tried many possible answers but nothing worked apart from using:

> var_dump("Track Title: " .
>   $response->Items->Item->Tracks->Disc->Track[0]->_);

But this only works if you know how many tracks there are for certain CD, I am calling 500 ASIN's at once. So basically I would like to parse the Tracks array into a String

```
  [Items] => stdClass Object
       (
        [Request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [IsValid] => True
            [ItemLookupRequest] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [IdType] => ASIN
                    [ItemId] => B000002OGL
                    [ResponseGroup] => Tracks
                    [VariationPage] => All
                )

        )

    [Item] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ASIN] => B000002OGL
            [Tracks] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Disc] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Track] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Mustang Sally
                                            [Number] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Take Me To The River
                                            [Number] => 2
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Chain Of Fools
                                            [Number] => 3
                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => The Dark End Of The Street
                                            [Number] => 4
                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Destination: Anywhere
                                            [Number] => 5
                                        )

                                    [5] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => I Can't Stand The Rain
                                            [Number] => 6
                                        )

                                    [6] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Try A Little Tenderness
                                            [Number] => 7
                                        )

                                    [7] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Treat Me Right
                                            [Number] => 8
                                        )

                                    [8] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Do Right Woman Do Right Man
                                            [Number] => 9
                                        )

                                    [9] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Mr. Pitiful
                                            [Number] => 10
                                        )

                                    [10] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => I Never Loved A Man
                                            [Number] => 11
                                        )

                                    [11] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => In The Midnight Hour
                                            [Number] => 12
                                        )

                                    [12] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Bye Bye Baby
                                            [Number] => 13
                                        )

                                    [13] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => Slip Away
                                            [Number] => 14
                                        )

                                )

                            [Number] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
         )
        )
```

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. If you just need to loop all the tracks of a disk, just use a nested foreach loop. First loop "Item" (or, to be honest, Item->tracks directly), then tracks and then disc. Foreach Track, then get the field "_" to get the song name and do whatever you need with that, either append that to a string or do what you need. How are all the results collected?

Comment: can you tell us the exact output you need..? it would be more helpful if you specify the output you need.

Comment: Hi @SahilGulati this is what I'm trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339328/how-to-parse-stdclass-from-amazon-api-response-to-return-string

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
foreach($response->Items->Item->Tracks->Disc->Track as $track){
  echo "Track Title: ". $track->_;// or track title
}
```

Comment: This will actually echo the number, not the track title. for the track title you problably meant `track->_`, right?

Comment: Still whenever I want to add the data to magento which my code does it returns in the logs that the "stdObject" cant be converted into a string.

Comment: I am not an expert in magento and since you have posted another question hope you find your answer.